If a Load Balancer reads SCTP data but redirects request based on simple Round Robin algorithm to backend over gRPC, is it L4 or L7 LB?
If a LB maintains, pool of gRPC connection to multiple backend servers.
When a SCTP connection comes, it reads the data using SCTPRead into buffer.
Selects a appropriate backend based on simple Round Robin algorithm.
And then forwards the buffered data to the selected backend.
I am confused, will this be a L4 load balancer, since it does not take decisions based on application level data or will it be L7 load balancer, since it reads the application data ?
